# Unit testing AngularJS Directives with Jest

Tags: angularjs, jestjs, angular-mock

I feel I am missing something crucial in this extremely simplified angular directive unit test:

```
import * as angular from 'angular'
import 'angular-mocks'

const app = angular.module('my-app', [])

app.directive('myDirective', () => ({
    template: 'this does not work either',
    link: (scope, element) => { // have also tried compile fn
        console.log('This does not log')
        element.html('Hi!')
    }
}))

describe('myDirective', () => {
    var element, scope

    beforeEach(app)

    beforeEach(inject(($rootScope, $compile) => {
        scope = $rootScope.$new()
        element = $compile('<my-directive />')(scope)
        scope.$digest()
    }))

    it('should actually do something', () => {
        expect(element.html()).toEqual('Hi!')
    })
})
```

When jest runs it appears the directive has not been linked/compiled/whatever

```
 FAIL  test/HtmlToPlaintextDirective.spec.js
  ● myDirective › should actually do something

    expect(received).toEqual(expected)

    Expected value to equal:
      "Hi!"
    Received:
      ""
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

You're right things don't work as expected when importing everything in a single file.

Digging into things it looks like you're running into some magic that Babel/Jest does to support browser scripts that rely on globals (like AngularJS).

What's happening is that your module's `angular` variable is *not* the same as the global `angular` variable that is visible to angular-mocks.

You can check this by running this at the top of one of your tests:

```
import * as angular from 'angular'
import 'angular-mocks'

console.log(angular === window.angular); // `false` in Jest!

console.log(angular.mock); // undefined
console.log(window.angular.mock); // `{...}` defined
```

To work around this you just need to use the global `angular` variable in your tests.

**src/__test__/all-in-one.test.js**:

```
import "angular";
import "angular-mocks";

/*
Work around Jest's window/global mock magic.

Use the global version of `angular` that has been augmented by angular-mocks.
*/
var angular = window.angular;


export var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('myDirective', () => ({
    link: (scope, element) => {
        console.log('This does log');
        scope.content = 'Hi!';
    },
    template: 'content: {{content}}'
}));


describe('myDirective', function(){
    var element;
    var scope;

    beforeEach(function(){
        angular.mock.module(app.name);
    });

    it('should do something', function(){
        inject(function(
            $rootScope,
            $compile
        ){
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            element = $compile('<my-directive></my-directive>')(scope);
            scope.$digest();
        });

        expect(element.html()).toEqual('content: Hi!');
    });
});
```

---

**Original answer:** (This worked because I was accidentally using the global version of `angular` inside my test.)

The Angular module under test isn't being initialised correctly in your tests.

Your call to `beforeEach(app)` isn't correct.

Instead you need to use `angular.mock.module("moduleName")` to initialise your module.

```
describe('myDirective', () => {
    var element, scope

    // You need to pass the module name to `angular.mock.module()`
    beforeEach(function(){
        angular.mock.module(app.name);
    });


    // Then you can set up and run your tests as normal:
    beforeEach(inject(($rootScope, $compile) => {
        scope = $rootScope.$new()
        element = $compile('<my-directive></my-directive>')(scope)
        scope.$digest()
    }))

    it('should actually do something', () => {
        expect(element.html()).toEqual('Hi!')
    })
});
```

And then your test works as expected for me:

```
 PASS  src\__test__\app.test.js
  myDirective
    √ should do something (46ms)
```

---

For reference, here is the full app and test:

**src/app/app.module.js**:

```
import * as angular from 'angular'

export var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('myDirective', () => ({
    link: (scope, element) => {
        console.log('This does log');
        scope.content = 'Hi!';
    },
    template: 'content: {{content}}'
}))
```

**src/__test__/app.test.js**:

```
import {app} from "../app/app.module";
import "angular-mocks";

describe('myDirective', function(){
    var element;
    var scope;

    beforeEach(function(){
        angular.mock.module(app.name);
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function(
        $rootScope,
        $compile
    ){
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        element = $compile('<my-directive></my-directive>')(scope);
        scope.$digest();
    }));

    it('should do something', function(){
        expect(element.html()).toEqual('content: Hi!');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Could you please tell me what versions you are running? As I copy-pasted your code exactly and still had my test fail as element.html() === ''. I am using angular: "1.6.3", angular-mocks: "1.6.3", jest: "18.1.0". Edit: upgraded jest to 19.0.2 and same issue. My only difference from your code is merging the two files (removing export+import)

Comment: I've updated my answer - you were right about it not working when everything was all in one file.

Comment: Can anyone show me how to configure jest with angular 1.6? I can't make it working, it seems you get this and started to write tests. Please provide any example repository link

Comment: @Sly_cardinal could you shed some light how to inject dependencies of module under testing to test file? I am facing the same issue as @captainclam and getting issues with module that uses angular  `ngSanitize` dependency module

Comment: @mtx probably best to ask a new question with specifics on any errors you're seeing and which dependencies you need to inject/mock. Ping me a link to the question here and I'll be happy to have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same baffling behavior a couple years later and I wanted to share what I found

If you transpile the test using babel and look at the imports you will find something similar to the following

```js
var _interopRequireWildcard = require("@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireWildcard");
var angular = _interopRequireWildcard(require("angular"));
require("angular-mocks");
```

`_interopRequireWildcard` currently has the following implementation

```js
function _interopRequireWildcard(obj) {
  if (obj && obj.__esModule) {
    return obj;
  } else {
    var newObj = {};

    if (obj != null) {
      for (var key in obj) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) {
          var desc = Object.defineProperty && Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor ? Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, key) : {};

          if (desc.get || desc.set) {
            Object.defineProperty(newObj, key, desc);
          } else {
            newObj[key] = obj[key];
          }
        }
      }
    }

    newObj.default = obj;
    return newObj;
  }
}
```

In short it **creates a new object** and copies all the properties from the imported object. This is why `angular === window.angular` is `false`. It also explains why `angular.mock` isn't defined, it didn't exist when `_interopRequireWildcard` made a copy of the module

Given that there are a couple additional ways to solve the problem in addition to the accepted answer

Instead of using `import * as angular from 'angular'` using `import angular from 'angular'` should avoid the behavior because `_interopRequireDefault` does not return a different object. (However, if you are using TypeScript it may not resolve the types for 'angular' correctly with this method)

Another option would be to import angular twice:

```
import 'angular'
import 'angular-mocks'
import * as angular from 'angular'
```